# Identical classes with different superclass

Tags: c#

I am dealing with a problem where I could use some help.

I have 2 versions of the same class with 100% identical code: 1 that inherits from another class and 1 that does not. Obviously I dont want to copy the code. What would be the best way to handle this problem?

```
class Simulator
{
    //Methods to simulate conveyors and other equipment.
}

class Conveyor1
{
    //Implementation
}

class Conveyor2 : Simulator
{
    //100% similar implementation as Conveyor1
}
```

Comment: If it's identically why do you even need two classes?  Maybe put the common code in another class and compose it into these two classes?  It's hard to say without more concrete examples of what is shared and what the classes are for.

Comment: what made the `Conveyor2` and `Conveyor1` different if you stated its 100% the same. does the `Conveyor2` written after a refactor..? @juharr is right, better off to use one of them if both are the exact same. we need to know the diffs between the two.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for your replies. The only difference between the classes Conveyor1 and Conveyor2 is that Conveyor2 inherits from class Simulator and Conveyor1 not.

Comment: If the code in `Conveyor2` is identical to the code in `Conveyor1` then that suggests that it doesn't actually use the fact that it inherits from `Simulator` at all... Can you clarify what purpose inheriting from `Simulator` has?

Comment: The simulator Class automatically adds fields and Methods to all classes that inherit from it. It is a generic class used for simulating conveyors, lifts, and other equipment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
interface IConveyor 
{
    void ConveyStuff();
}

class Simulator<T> 
{
    void Simulate(T thingToSimulate)
    {
        //Do something to simulate
    }
}

class RealConveyor : IConveyor
{
    public void ConveyStuff()
    {
    }
}

class SimulatedConveyor : Simulator<IConveyor>, IConveyor
{
    public void ConveyStuff()
    {
        Simulate(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply John. Could you tell me why you declare class SimulatedConveyor as SimulatedConveyor<IConveyor>? Why does the <IConveyor> type definition do?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake. Should have been `SimulatedConveyor : Simulator<IConveyor>, IConveyor`. I've edited the example. The idea here is to declare "A SimulatedConveyor is a type of Simulator that can simulate Conveyors, and also acts like a Conveyor."